# onChildRemoved() getting called multiple number of times

Tags: android, firebase

I am using firebase database for my android app. I have set `ChildEventListener` for one of the firebase nodes. When a immediate child of that node is removed the `onChildRemoved()` should get called exactly one time, but in my case it is getting called multiple number of times.

The reason I think why this is happening is because I have set `ChildEventListener` for the same node at multiple places throughout my app, because when I set `ChildEventListener` one time in my app ,the `onChildRemoved()` method gets called once per child deleted which is as expected.

**Fragment A**

```
firebaseData.child("patients").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
       dataChangedforListviewInFragmentA(dataSnapShot);
    }
});
```

**Fragment B**

```
firebaseData.child("patients").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
       dataChangedforListviewInFragmentB(dataSnapShot);
    }
});
```

**Fragment C**

```
firebaseData.child("patients").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
       dataChangedforListviewInFragmentC(dataSnapShot);
    }
});
```

In method `dataChangedforListviewInFragment()` I set the `listView` using the updated data. 
When a immediate child of node `patients` is delete the `onChildRemoved()` in `Fragment C` is called multiple times.

Is it possible to write `ChildEventListener` at multiple places in my app and yet get its callback methods to get called the right number of times. Thanks.

Comment: Next time, instead of describing the code, please include the minimum code to reproduce your problem in the question.

Comment: Sorry but there is no minimum code here. There is either no code or a lot of code which would have made the question counter intuitive instead.  The question is pretty self explanatory  in itself, if there is something unclear to you I would be happy to explain in a more detailed fashion if needs be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add multiple listeners to the same location, each of those listeners will be invoked when the relevant event happens.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");
// Create a listener
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
};
// Attach listeners to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

With the above setup, when the value of `posts` changes, the listener will be invoked twice and the new value will be printed twice. This is exactly what is supposed to happen.

If you only want the listener to be invoked once, you should only add it to the reference once. This can be easily done by tracking if you've already added it.

```
boolean isListenerAdded = false;
// then in the first place you'r adding a listener, the code will be executed
if (!listenerAdded) {
    ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
    isListenerAdded = true;
}
// and in the other place, the code will be skipped
if (!listenerAdded) {
    ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
    isListenerAdded = true;
}
```

If the listeners are within the same fragment/activity, you can just keep the boolean in a member field of the activity. If the listeners are in different activities, you could keep the boolean in the SharedPreferences. But you should really consider in that case [removing the listeners](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching) in each activity's `onPause()`.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    if (listenerAdded) {
        ref.removeEventListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have three listeners spread out across three different fragments. I ideally want to set just one listener but can't because I use the value from the listener to set  `listviews` present in each of the fragments .If I set just one listener say in my `fragment A` then the data coming from that listener will also go in the other two fragments as well which would make code complicated. Although removing the listeners on `onPause()` should probably help me. If there is a better alternative(design pattern) for my problem please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem. If you have two places where you need to add the same data to a different view, using two listeners sounds perfect. Note: the data will be retrieved only once if that is a concern. But if that's not, consider adding a minimal reproduction of your problem to your question to help me understand the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: " The data will be retrieved only once" - what does this mean? Does this mean that the data will be retrieved by only one of the two listeners? In my case I get the data in both the listeners. And then what would " the data will be retrieved more then once would mean"? Sorry If I sound very naive but this statement just went over my head ,would be great if you clarify.

Comment: I don't want my data to be retrieved only once, hence removing listener at `onPause()` of fragment is not an option. But if I don't remove the listeners then their callback methods gets called multiple number of times. Here I have posted the code of my fragment please take a look -> https://gist.github.com/Parag-indiacom/a9574dd6225cfdab3edb

Comment: If you add a listener in `Fragment. onCreateView()`, you should typically remove it in `Fragment.onDestroyView()`. There's really not a lot more I can say about it. From looking at your fragments, they really should follow that advice.